# Filter Data from RecyclerView Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, searchview, firebaseui

I am trying to implement a searchview in my action bar and for that to filter the RecyclerView Data that I retrieved from Firebase. Right now I am looking for the code that I need to add to the recycleradapter to be able to filter the retrieved data.
This is how I added the recyclerView to my MainActivity.

```
        Query query = mRef.orderByChild("city");
        // everything else
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<City, CityViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<City, CityViewHolder>(
                        City.class,
                        R.layout.city_starter,
                        CityViewHolder.class,
                        query
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(CityViewHolder viewHolder, City city, int position) {
                        viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(),
                                city.getCity());
                    }

                    // for click of parent item
                    @Override
                    public CityViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                        CityViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);

                        viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new CityViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                                //get Data from Firebase
                                String cCity = getItem(position).getCity();


                                // pass this data to new activity
                                Intent secondMainActivity = new Intent(view.getContext(), SecondMainActivity.class);
                                secondMainActivity.putExtra("city", cCity);
                                startActivity(secondMainActivity);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                                // possible to implement another way of interacting for a long click
                            }
                        });

                        return viewHolder;
                    }
                };

        // set adapter to recyclerview
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

Is there anybody who is able to help?
Thank you :)

This is what I found searching for solutions but I don't get it how to adapt it to my code:

```
public void filter(String text) {
items.clear();
if(text.isEmpty()){
    items.addAll(itemsCopy);
} else{
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    for(PhoneBookItem item: itemsCopy){
        if(item.name.toLowerCase().contains(text) || item.phone.toLowerCase().contains(text)){
            items.add(item);
        }
    }
}
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use android's Filterable interface..

[Follow this link for example](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/)

Firstly `implements Filterable` to your adapter class.. You can use another array list of same type you are using for storing and showing filtered items.

Implements Filterable interface's method `getFilter()`

Example Code...

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                contactListFiltered = contactList;
            } else {
                List<Contact> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Contact row : contactList) {

                    // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                    // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                    if (row.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getPhone().contains(charSequence)) {
                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }
                }

                contactListFiltered = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = contactListFiltered;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            contactListFiltered = (ArrayList<Contact>) filterResults.values;

            // refresh the list with filtered data
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Add search view into your toolbar....

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    // listening to search query text change
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // filter recycler view when query submitted
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            // filter recycler view when text is changed
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // close search view on back button pressed
    if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
        searchView.setIconified(true);
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```