# How to do a search in listview with data from the database

Tags: android, searchview

I have difficulty making a listview search on Android, please help me.

this is my getter setter, the name is toko.java

```
public class Toko {

    private String no;
    private String str_id;
    private String nama;
    private String alamat;
    private String kabupaten;
    private String provinsi;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String sms;

    public void setNo(String no) {
        this.no = no;
    }
    String getNo() {
        return no;
    }

    public void setStr_id (String str_id) {
        this.str_id = str_id;
    }
    String getStr_id() {
        return str_id;
    }

    public void setNama (String nama) {
        this.nama = nama;
    }
    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }

    public void setAlamat (String alamat) {
        this.alamat = alamat;
    }
    String getAlamat() {
        return alamat;
    }

    public void setKabupaten (String kabupaten) {
        this.kabupaten = kabupaten;
    }
    String getKabupaten() {
        return kabupaten;
    }

    public void setProvinsi (String provinsi) {
        this.provinsi = provinsi;
    }
    String getProvinsi() {
        return provinsi;
    }

    public void setLatitude (String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude (String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
    String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setSms (String sms) {
        this.sms = sms;
    }
    String getSms() {
        return sms;
    }
}
```

this is my adapter, the name is TokoAdapter.java

```
public class TokoAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    //private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private ArrayList<Toko> data_toko = new ArrayList<Toko>();
    private List<String> originalData = null;
    private List<String> filteredData = null;
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public TokoAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Toko> d) {
        data_toko = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) a.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data_toko.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data_toko.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_toko, null);
        }
        TextView no = vi.findViewById(R.id.no);
        TextView str_id = vi.findViewById(R.id.str_id);
        TextView nama = vi.findViewById(R.id.nama);
        TextView alamat = vi.findViewById(R.id.alamat);
        TextView kabupaten = vi.findViewById(R.id.kabupaten);
        TextView provinsi = vi.findViewById(R.id.provinsi);
        TextView latitude = vi.findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        TextView longitude = vi.findViewById(R.id.longitude);
        TextView sms = vi.findViewById(R.id.sms);


        Toko daftar_toko = data_toko.get(position);
        no.setText(daftar_toko.getNo());
        str_id.setText(daftar_toko.getStr_id());
        nama.setText(daftar_toko.getNama());
        alamat.setText(daftar_toko.getAlamat());
        kabupaten.setText(daftar_toko.getKabupaten());
        provinsi.setText(daftar_toko.getProvinsi());
        latitude.setText(daftar_toko.getLatitude());
        longitude.setText(daftar_toko.getLongitude());
        sms.setText(daftar_toko.getSms());
        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            final List<String> list = originalData;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<>(count);

            String filterableString;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

this is my layout code, the name is activity_read_toko.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".crud.toko.ReadTokoActivity"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/key"
            android:layout_width="347dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/search_view"
            android:hint="@string/pencarian_nama_toko"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/toko_btnSearch"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_toko"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my activity code, the name is ReadTokoActivity.java

```
public class ReadTokoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, TextWatcher {

    ListView list;


    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    ArrayList<Toko> daftar_toko = new ArrayList<Toko>();
    JSONArray daftarToko, daftarSearchToko = null;
    ImageButton BtnSearch;
    TokoAdapter adapter;
    EditText Query;
    String query, url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_toko);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_toko);
        BtnSearch = findViewById(R.id.toko_btnSearch);
        Query = findViewById(R.id.key);

//        BtnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);

        Query.addTextChangedListener(this);

        //jalankan ReadDataTask
        ReadDataTask m= (ReadDataTask) new ReadDataTask().execute();
    }



    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class ReadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReadTokoActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Mohon Tunggu..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sText) {
            return getDataList();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Exception Caught")){
                Toast.makeText(ReadTokoActivity.this, "Unable to connect to server,please check your internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("no results")){
                Toast.makeText(ReadTokoActivity.this, "Data empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                adapter = new TokoAdapter(ReadTokoActivity.this,daftar_toko);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                //Adapter menampilkan data mahasiswa ke dalam listView
            }
        }

        //method untuk memperoleh daftar mahasiswa dari JSON
        String getDataList(){
            Toko tempMarker = new Toko();
            List<NameValuePair> parameter = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            try {
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(Konfigurasi.URL_READ_TOKO,"POST", parameter);

                int success = json.getInt(Konfigurasi.TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) { //Ada record Data (SUCCESS = 1)
                    //Getting Array of daftar_mhs
                    daftarToko = json.getJSONArray(Konfigurasi.TAG_TOKO);
                    // looping through All daftar_mhs
                    for (int i = 0; i < daftarToko.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject c = daftarToko.getJSONObject(i);
                        tempMarker = new Toko();
                        tempMarker.setNo(c.getString(Konfigurasi.TAG_NO));
                        tempMarker.setStr_id(c.getString(Konfigurasi.TAG_STR_ID));
                        tempMarker.setNama(c.getString(Konfigurasi.TAG_NAMA));
                        tempMarker.setAlamat(c.getString(Konfigurasi.TAG_ALAMAT));
                        tempMarker.setKabupaten(c.getString(Konfigurasi.TAG_KABUPATEN));
                        tempMarker.setProvinsi(c.getString(Konfigurasi.TAG_PROVINSI));
                        tempMarker.setLatitude(c.getString(Konfigurasi.TAG_LATITUDE));
                        tempMarker.setLongitude(c.getString(Konfigurasi.TAG_LONGITUDE));
                        tempMarker.setSms(c.getString(Konfigurasi.TAG_SMS));
                        daftar_toko.add(tempMarker);
                    }
                    return "OK";
                }else{
                    //Tidak Ada Record Data (SUCCESS = 0)
                    return "no results";
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception Caught";
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String text = Query.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

and when I enter keywords in edittext, there is no change in listview.
please solve my problem.
and I search my problem in google, and none of them succeeded.

Comment: [Check out this link and compare with your code and check what you are missing...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900488/filter-data-from-recyclerview-firebase/52986400#52986400)

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378981/how-to-use-searchview-in-toolbar-android/49064027#49064027

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> While you get your string in after TextChanged

```
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

     String names = s.toString();
     List<Toko> newList = new ArrayList<>();

     for (Toko r : cityList){ 
        //citylist will be your daftar_toko list
        String name = r.getCity();
        if (name.toLowerCase().contains(names.toLowerCase())){
              newList.add(r);
        }
     }

     //make seFilter method in adapter and pass your new list
     mAdapter.setFilter(newList);

  }
```

> Making method in Adapter

```
  public void setFilter(List<Toko> newList){
    data_toko = new ArrayList<>();
    data_toko.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> - Try This

```
  msearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

            int textlength = s.length();
            ArrayList<SqliteGetSet> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<SqliteGetSet>();

            for(SqliteGetSet c: list){

                if (textlength <= c.getName().length()) {

                       if (c.getName().toLowerCase().contains(s.toString().toLowerCase())
                                        || c.getMno().toLowerCase().contains(s.toString().toLowerCase())) 
                       {
                             tempArrayList.add(c);
                       }
                  }
             }

             adapter = new SqliteAdapter(SqliteExample.this,R.layout.row_sqlite_list, tempArrayList);
             listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
  });
```

> msearch - Edittext name
>           SqliteGetSet - Model Class