# How to configure searchable with the option menu on action bar in android

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my activity manifest file.......

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.NavigationDrawer"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Here I have declare the option menu

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

        return true;
    }
```

but searchable is not showing as option menu please help me regarding this matter

Comment: Try this. http://codesfor.in/how-to-implement-searchview-in-actionbar-in-android/

Comment: Try this answer..It works for me... [Try this it works for me...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900488/filter-data-from-recyclerview-firebase/52986400#52986400)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

in OncreateView